# Firefox mobile: Links getting activated by touching elsewhere

Tags: firefox, mobile, hyperlink, scale, viewport

I've got a strange probleme here.

If I have this line in the HEAD part

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1200,initial-scale=2,minimum-scale=2">
```

touching the lines which are not links in the following example causes one of the links to get activated:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.example.com">example</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.test.com">test</a></li>
    <li>Text in between</li>
    <li>Even more text in between</li>
    <li><a href="http://www.something.com">something</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.other.com">other</a></li>
</ul>
```

This seems to happen only with that line in the HEAD part. Everything is okay with Chrome and Android Browser.

Is there any way to solve this?

**Edit:**

It gets even worse if I make the line-height small, for example this way:

```
li { font-family:Arial; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; line-height:12px;}
```

Now whether I use that META element or not, it is almost impossible to tap the texts in between without activating one of the links. Again only in Firefox mobile browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found a solution, however, I don't like it very much.

Adding an "onclick" attribute (whether empty or not) to each unlinked element makes it touchable in Firefox browser.

This can be achieved through a small JavaScript loop.

Better solutions are appreciated!